find minimal polynomials
I have the following task:
Let $\alpha$ be a complex number satisfying $\alpha ^3 +2\alpha -1 =0$ find its minimal polynomial and the minimal polynomal of $\alpha^2 +\alpha$.
For the first part tried to find conditions for a,b,c s.t
$x^3+2x^2 -1 = (x^2+ax+b)(x+c)$, but I didnt suceed, in fact I looked at the real root in wolframalpha and it seems quite hard to compute it explictly so maybe there is another way?
for the second part I found out that $(\alpha^2 +\alpha)^2 + \alpha^2 +\alpha + (2\alpha +2) = 0 $ here I think Im on the right track but I dont know how to get rid of the last term.

See the answer I just wrote to explain the use of SAGE for such a task.

Everything happens inside the field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. It is a 3-dimensional space spanned by the $\Bbb{Q}$-basis $\mathcal{B}=\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$. One way of seeing that is to check that none of the rational candidate zeros of $f(x)=x^3+2x-1$ offered by the rational root actually are roots of $f$. As a cubic $f$ is then irreducible, and the rest follows.
Let's figure out what multiplication by $\beta=\alpha^2+\alpha$ does to the elements of the basis, and write the outcomes using $\mathcal{B}$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta\cdot1&=\alpha+\alpha^2&=0\cdot1+1\cdot\alpha+1\cdot\alpha^2,\\
\beta\cdot\alpha&=\alpha^2+\alpha^3=1-2\alpha+\alpha^2&=1\cdot1-2\cdot\alpha+1\cdot\alpha^2,\\
\beta\cdot\alpha^2&=\alpha-2\alpha^2+\alpha^3=1-\alpha-2\alpha^2&=1\cdot1-1\cdot\alpha-2\cdot\alpha^2.
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
$$
The system of equations $(1)$ can be viewed as saying that the column vector $\vec{v}=(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)^T$ is an eigenvector of the matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}0&1&1\\ 1&-2&1\\1&-1&2\end{array}\right)
$$
belonging to the eigenvalue $\beta$. So, by linear algebra, $\beta$ must be a zero of the characteristic polynomial
$$
\chi_A(x)=\det(xI_3-A)=x^3+4x^2+3x-4.
$$
As $\beta$ cannot be rational, and three is a prime, we must have $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ must be $\chi_A(x)$.

Somewhat surprisingly I could not find a good duplicate, so I post this answer. The method is well known, and related to the famous Cayley-Hamilton theorem of linear algebra.

Related

Jonathan Lubin also seems to recommend it.

The first paragraph kinda explains that. Are you familiar with the rational root test? Because the polynomial has degree three either it has a rational root, or it is irreducible.

ah yes now I understand thank you

Linking this answer by Georges Elencwajg.

For the second part, in addition to Jyrki's answer, there are the following two amazing alternative methods to find the minimal polynomial:

Compute $f(x)=Res(x^3+2x-1, y-x^2-x)$ with respect to the indeterminate $x$, where $Res(f(x),g(x))$ is the resultant of the two univariate polynomials $f(x), g(x)$. This returns a multiple of the minimum polynomial. Since in the given case $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$, $f(x)$ is already the minimum polynomial.

Compute the reduced Gröbner Basis of the polynomial ideal $(x^3+2x-1, y-x^2-x)$ with respect to the lex term ordering with $x>y$. It contains one element in the variable $y$ alone, which is the minimum polynomial. This is described e.g. in Adams and Loustaunau "Introduction to Gröbner Bases", chapter 2.6.


Both methods return the minimum polynomial with one single command in a CAS (Computer Algebra System), e.g. in the Wolfram Alpha Calculator.
